# Display true filesize upload limit in PHP applications when setting it via nginx

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, upload

As discussed in many threads, I have set

```
client_max_body_size 2M;
```

in my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

and

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

in one of my virtual hosts config.

And it works, as in the upload of files >2MB fails on virtual hosts than don't have the 100M directive.

The problem is that this is not reported by PHP applications, like WordPress. They still show a 100MB limit. And when someone tried to upload something >2MB, they see:

*Unexpected response from the server. The file may have been uploaded successfully. Check in the Media Library or reload the page.*

Is there a way to communicate the "true" max filesize limit to PHP applications, even if it's set at the webserver level?

Answer (score 1):

[WordPress](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/media.php#L3357), like most PHP scripts, didn't use nginx configuration's `client_max_body_size`, rather they used PHP's [`upload_max_filesize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) and [`post_max_size`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading).

You can try to change this, but if you do so, you may need to have two `php-fpm` service running rather than one, reading different `php.ini` file, to have multiple `upload_max_filesize` configurations.

PS: Sorry about bad PHP manual links, if you used their correct fragment identifier, they tend to be covered by their header. Try to scroll up on [this `post-max-size` fragment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size).